# Split dataframe column of separated key-value pairs into new columns

Tags: r, key-value

I have a dataframe with 5 columns, 4 of which are "normal" values and the 5th is a set of delimiter-separated key-value pairs of the form

```
key1 = value1 | key2 = value2 | key3 = value3
```

There are no duplicate keys in a single row, but there's no guarantee they'll be in the same order in each row or that the number of key/value pairs will be the same in every row.

What's the easiest way to get the values into ~15 columns, named correctly for their key?

Comment: Please share the output of `dput(head(your_dataframe_here))` to make your problem reproducible. Also show expected output and what you've tried yourself.

Comment: @Mako212 Not quite a dupe, the data format is different.

Comment: This is a common issue, working with large dataframes that include a single column comprised of key-value pairs.  See the sample data I've provided below, and a clean dplyr-based solution.

Comment: @Mako212 This should not be marked duplicate.  This question asks how to decompose a key-value pair column present in a dataframe.   The other asks about reading in files that contain such a field.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is an alternative that will maintain non-key-value columns intact using tidyr, dplyr and stringr.

**Create test data**

```
testdf <- data_frame(col1 = paste0("a", 1:4), col2 = paste0("b", 1:4), 
              col3 = paste0("c", 5:8),
              col4 = paste0("enst", 12099:12102),
              col5 = c("bang=1 | dong=2 | foo=6", "bang=2 | dong=3 | zups=foo", 
                       "dimbo=2 | bang=6 | jumbo=7 | zoo=camel", "boo=0"))
```

**Code**

```
library(stringr)
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

KVsep <- fixed(" | ")  #key-value separator
Vsep <- fixed("=")     #value separator

newDF <-  testdf %>%
  mutate(KVpairs = str_split(col5, KVsep)) %>%
  unnest(KVpairs) %>%
  separate(KVpairs, into = c("key", "value"), Vsep) %>%
  spread(key, value) %>%
  select(-col5)
```

**Result**

```
> newDF
# A tibble: 4 x 12
  col1  col2  col3  col4      bang  boo   dimbo dong  foo   jumbo zoo   zups 
* <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>     <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
1 a1    b1    c5    enst12099 1     NA    NA    2     6     NA    NA    NA   
2 a2    b2    c6    enst12100 2     NA    NA    3     NA    NA    NA    foo  
3 a3    b3    c7    enst12101 6     NA    2     NA    NA    7     camel NA   
4 a4    b4    c8    enst12102 NA    0     NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
>
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, I don't suppose there are any specialized functions for this but it's not complicated to do with  a little programming.

```
c2nv <- function(x){
  # part 1 - convert vector to name-value pairs
  x <- strsplit(x, "|", fixed=TRUE) # split at |, then split at =
  x <- sapply(x,  function(.) t(trimws(sapply(lapply(., strsplit, "="), "[[", 1))))
  x1 <- lapply(x, function(.) setNames( .[,2], .[,1]))
  # part 2 - find all existing names in all rows
  u <- sort(unique(unlist(lapply(x1, names))))  # unique keys
  res <- t(sapply(x1, function(.) .[u]))   # look at each key in each row
  colnames(res) <- u
  res
}
```

### sample data

```
col <- c("bang=1 | dong = 2 | foo = 6", "bang1=2 | dong = 3 | zups = foo", 
"dimbo = 2 | bang = 6 | jumbo = 7 | zoo = camel", "boo = 0")
```

### processing the sample data

```
> c2nv (col)
     bang bang1 boo dimbo dong foo jumbo zoo     zups 
[1,] "1"  NA    NA  NA    "2"  "6" NA    NA      NA   
[2,] NA   "2"   NA  NA    "3"  NA  NA    NA      "foo"
[3,] "6"  NA    NA  "2"   NA   NA  "7"   "camel" NA   
[4,] NA   NA    "0" NA    NA   NA  NA    NA      NA   
>
```

Comment: This is great. Assuming that each key can only appear once, is there a way to flatten the output into a single row for each row?

Comment: Hi, I'm not sure I understand -- can you explain what you expect the output to be like?

Comment: Sorry, I misread your response, it's working as expected. Thanks again