# split a column of key value pairs on a delimiter and insert keys as new columns

Tags: r

I have this data:

```
data <- data.frame(INFO=c(
  "IMPUTED;FREQ=TOPMED:1,4.534e-05|dbGaP_PopFreq:0.9998,0.0001686;GENEINFO=LOC105372733:105372733;GNO;INT;R3;RS=1216947677;SSR=0;VC=INDEL;dbSNPBuildID=151",
  "IMPUTED;FREQ=GnomAD:0.9999,8.488e-05|TOPMED:1,2.267e-05|dbGaP_PopFreq:1,0;GENEINFO=LOC105372733:105372733;GNO;INT;R3;RS=1415762563;SSR=0;VC=INDEL;dbSNPBuildID=151",
  "IMPUTED;FREQ=TOPMED:1,3.778e-06|dbGaP_PopFreq:1,0;GENEINFO=LOC105372733:105372733;GNO;INT;R3;RS=1237792419;SSR=0;VC=DEL;dbSNPBuildID=155"
    )
)
```

I want to split the `INFO` col on delimiter ';' and within those fields there are key value pairs delimited '=' I want the keys to be the names of new columns and the values to be elements of the rows. Where there is no value (eg for key "IMPUTED") I want the the values to be empty string.

sort of like this

```
data_new <- data.frame(IMPUTED=c('', '', ''), 
FREQ=c('TOPMED:1,4.534e-05|dbGaP_PopFreq:0.9998,0.0001686', 
'GnomAD:0.9999,8.488e-05|TOPMED:1,2.267e-05|dbGaP_PopFreq:1,0', 
'TOPMED:1,3.778e-06|dbGaP_PopFreq:1,0'))
```

I am stuck on this and I won't always know the key names and I have millions of rows to do this to, so I would prefer not to use anything with loops

I tried this

```
library(stringr)
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

KVsep <- fixed(";")  #key-value separator
Vsep <- fixed("=")     #value separator

newDF <-  data %>%
  mutate(KVpairs = str_split(INFO, KVsep)) %>%
  unnest(KVpairs) %>%
  separate(KVpairs, into = c("key", "value"), Vsep) %>%
  spread(key, value) %>%
  select(-INFO)
```

from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53876274/split-dataframe-column-of-separated-key-value-pairs-into-new-columns), but get

```
Error in `check_not_stringr_pattern()`:
! `sep` can't use modifiers from stringr.
```

Comment: Remove the parenthesis in KVsep and Vsep like `KVsep <- ";"  #key-value separator
Vsep <- "="`. Does this work for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A somewhat pedestrian approach would be:

```r
do.call(rbind, lapply(strsplit(data$INFO, ";"), strsplit, "=") |>
  lapply(function(x) dplyr::as_tibble(t(sapply(x, function(y) {
    setNames(if(length(y) == 1) "" else y[2], y[1])})))))
#> # A tibble: 3 x 10
#>   IMPUTED FREQ         GENEINFO GNO   INT   R3    RS    SSR   VC    dbSNPBuildID
#>   <chr>   <chr>        <chr>    <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>       
#> 1 ""      TOPMED:1,4.~ LOC1053~ ""    ""    ""    1216~ 0     INDEL 151         
#> 2 ""      GnomAD:0.99~ LOC1053~ ""    ""    ""    1415~ 0     INDEL 151         
#> 3 ""      TOPMED:1,3.~ LOC1053~ ""    ""    ""    1237~ 0     DEL   155
```

<sup>Created on 2023-07-21 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

An approach using `pivot_wider` to construct the desired key-value wide format

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

KVsep <- ";"
Vsep <- "="

data %>% 
  mutate(st_sp = strsplit(INFO, KVsep), INFO = NULL) %>% 
  unnest(st_sp) %>% 
  separate(st_sp, c("key", "value"), Vsep, fill="right") %>% 
  mutate(row = row_number(), .by = key, value = replace_na(value, "")) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = key, values_from = value) %>%  
  select(-row)
# A tibble: 3 × 10
  IMPUTED FREQ               GENEI…¹ GNO   INT   R3    RS    SSR   VC    dbSNP…²
  <chr>   <chr>              <chr>   <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>  
1 ""      TOPMED:1,4.534e-0… LOC105… ""    ""    ""    1216… 0     INDEL 151    
2 ""      GnomAD:0.9999,8.4… LOC105… ""    ""    ""    1415… 0     INDEL 151    
3 ""      TOPMED:1,3.778e-0… LOC105… ""    ""    ""    1237… 0     DEL   155    
# … with abbreviated variable names ¹​GENEINFO, ²​dbSNPBuildID
```

Answer (score 0):

The first line of your pipe tries to make a list column (`str_split` will return
a list) to be `unnest`ed in the second step, but `data.frame` won't make a list
column like this. If you want to use the tidyverse workflow for this I suggest
as a first step making a `tibble` of your data frame, that will accept the list
column as intended:

```r
library('dplyr')
library('tidyr')
library('stringr')

data = as_tibble(data)

data |>
  mutate(
    KVpairs = str_split(INFO, ';'),
    .keep = 'unused'
  ) |>
  glimpse()
```

```
## Rows: 3
## Columns: 1
## $ KVpairs <list> <"IMPUTED", "FREQ=TOPMED:1,4.534e-05|dbGaP_PopFreq:0.9998,0.0…
```

Now we have a list column that we can `unnest`. I'll add a unique `ìd` at this
point so we can keep track of original observations:

```r
data |>
  mutate(
    id = row_number(),
    KVpairs = str_split(INFO, ';'),
    .keep = 'unused'
  ) |>
  unnest(cols = KVpairs)
```

```
## # A tibble: 30 × 2
##       id KVpairs                                               
##    <int> <chr>                                                 
##  1     1 IMPUTED                                               
##  2     1 FREQ=TOPMED:1,4.534e-05|dbGaP_PopFreq:0.9998,0.0001686
##  3     1 GENEINFO=LOC105372733:105372733                       
##  4     1 GNO                                                   
##  5     1 INT                                                   
##  6     1 R3                                                    
##  7     1 RS=1216947677                                         
##  8     1 SSR=0                                                 
##  9     1 VC=INDEL                                              
## 10     1 dbSNPBuildID=151                                      
## # ℹ 20 more rows
```

To get to the final columns we can use `pivot_wider` (`spread` has been
superseded by this function), but first it would be advisable to take care of
the improper key value pairs (e.g. `IMPUTED`). Since the desired output is to
have `''` values for these columns, appending an `=` when there's no `=` would
do the job:

```r
data |>
  mutate(
    id = row_number(),
    KVpairs = str_split(INFO, ';'),
    .keep = 'unused'
  ) |>
  unnest(cols = KVpairs) |>
  mutate(
    KVpairs = if_else(grepl('=', KVpairs), KVpairs, paste0(KVpairs, '='))
  )
```

```
## # A tibble: 30 × 2
##       id KVpairs                                               
##    <int> <chr>                                                 
##  1     1 IMPUTED=                                              
##  2     1 FREQ=TOPMED:1,4.534e-05|dbGaP_PopFreq:0.9998,0.0001686
##  3     1 GENEINFO=LOC105372733:105372733                       
##  4     1 GNO=                                                  
##  5     1 INT=                                                  
##  6     1 R3=                                                   
##  7     1 RS=1216947677                                         
##  8     1 SSR=0                                                 
##  9     1 VC=INDEL                                              
## 10     1 dbSNPBuildID=151                                      
## # ℹ 20 more rows
```

We also need to get the keys and values in their respective columns,
for this we can use `separate_delim_wider`, that has superseded `separate`:

```r
data |>
  mutate(
    id = row_number(),
    KVpairs = str_split(INFO, ';'),
    .keep = 'unused'
  ) |>
  unnest(cols = KVpairs) |>
  mutate(
    KVpairs = if_else(grepl('=', KVpairs), KVpairs, paste0(KVpairs, '='))
  ) |>
  separate_wider_delim(
    cols = KVpairs,
    delim = '=',
    names = c('key', 'value')
    )
```

```
## # A tibble: 30 × 3
##       id key          value                                              
##    <int> <chr>        <chr>                                              
##  1     1 IMPUTED      ""                                                 
##  2     1 FREQ         "TOPMED:1,4.534e-05|dbGaP_PopFreq:0.9998,0.0001686"
##  3     1 GENEINFO     "LOC105372733:105372733"                           
##  4     1 GNO          ""                                                 
##  5     1 INT          ""                                                 
##  6     1 R3           ""                                                 
##  7     1 RS           "1216947677"                                       
##  8     1 SSR          "0"                                                
##  9     1 VC           "INDEL"                                            
## 10     1 dbSNPBuildID "151"                                              
## # ℹ 20 more rows
```

Finally `pivot_wider`:

```r
data |>
  mutate(
    id = row_number(),
    KVpairs = str_split(INFO, ';'),
    .keep = 'unused'
  ) |>
  unnest(cols = KVpairs) |>
  mutate(
    KVpairs = if_else(grepl('=', KVpairs), KVpairs, paste0(KVpairs, '='))
  ) |>
  separate_wider_delim(
    cols = KVpairs,
    delim = '=',
    names = c('key', 'value')
    ) |>
    pivot_wider(
      names_from = key,
      values_from = value
    )
```

```
## # A tibble: 3 × 11
##      id IMPUTED FREQ   GENEINFO GNO   INT   R3    RS    SSR   VC    dbSNPBuildID
##   <int> <chr>   <chr>  <chr>    <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>       
## 1     1 ""      TOPME… LOC1053… ""    ""    ""    1216… 0     INDEL 151         
## 2     2 ""      GnomA… LOC1053… ""    ""    ""    1415… 0     INDEL 151         
## 3     3 ""      TOPME… LOC1053… ""    ""    ""    1237… 0     DEL   155
```

Hope this helps. Please note I'm assuming here that `IMPUTED`, `GNO` and the
like will always exist and have a unique value. If this is not the case then the
output will be hard to predict.